# Prevent Softkeyboard from opening on EditText Focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I need to prevent softkeyboard from showing up when Edit Text gains focus or if user taps on the edit text because user has to use a barcode scanner as an input method. But I need is open the keyboard when user clicks/taps a specific button.

I have tried **focusableInTouchMode** property and it works fine in preventing the softkeyboard from popping but it won't let the edit text gain focus.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

myEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // showMyDialog();
    }
});

myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            // showMyDialog();
        }
    }
});
```

Try this.... Just return null or anything on onclicklistner..

Njoy.. :)
And m using it so don't tell me its not working.. LOL..

I have one condition that if user clicks on edittext then it ll pops DatePicker Dialog and its working.
So njoy dude...: ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the keyboard using this code

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I believe this above line will do same as puttin **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"** in manifest file, but I added the line you just gave in onCreate function but it still is opening the soft keyboard whenever I taps the Edit Text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use stateAlwaysHidded. Either in runtime as in the first answer, or directly in your project Manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

This will prevent keyboard from appearing during onCreate/onResume.

To prevent keyboard appearing after clicking EditText, you can place some blank view with transparent backround right on top of your EditText:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="editTextWidth"
    android:layout_height="editTextWidth"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

The key attribute here is `android:clickable="true"`. It will prevent from gaining focus on click (actually users will click on this blank view, not EditText).

Then, when user clicks special button you've mentioned, you just remove this blank view and call `editText.requestFocus()`